# Power Bi Split column from variables

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

I have a column with cell content structured like " [User] performed action on [ActionItemId] in category [Category] "

I am looking to split [User], [ActionItemId] and [Category] into their own columns.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that in Power Query when you load the data into Power BI.

In the Query Editor, duplicate the column (just for backup purposes), then split the duplicated column and use a custom delimiter, which you define as the text " performed action on " (note the spaces in the delimiter string).

Now you have two columns, the first has the user, the second starts with the ActionItemID. Split the second column by the custom delimiter " in category " (note the spaces in the delimiter string).

Now you have User, ActionItemId, and the Category in separate columns. Rename columns as you please.